# Interprocess sharing of persistent buffers with GL_EXT_memory_object

Tags: windows, opengl, vulkan

I am trying to understand GL_EXT_memory_object and the Vulkan equivalents.  And I want to know if it is possible to share OpenGL persistent buffers across processes somehow?  For example to allow different processes to write data to the same buffer for upload without needing interprocess memory copying or mapping (ie each process writes to an allocated region, somehow synchronise, and one process then renders using the data).

So far I came across persistent buffers not working in a case mentioned here:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/NV/NV_memory_attachment.txt

"Client-mappable resources are supported but not when they are persistent. When memory is attached resource must be unmapped."

Also I am not sure what that may imply regards different processes mapping the same resource for writing with glMapBuffer() etc.

If this isn't possible in OpenGL, is it possible in Vulkan or in an nVidia specific way?

Comment: It seems to me that the existing external_memory extensions are adequate for this task. NVIDIA's extension is really about removing the "storage" requirement (that is, not requiring `Tex/BufferStorage` and instead allowing `TexImage/BufferData` functions which allow reallocating and other nonsense). That's why persistent mapping isn't allowed, since reallocating persistent mapped memory is a nonsensical idea. Why do you feel that the existing external_memory functionality doesn't let you do what you are trying to do?

Comment: As I understand it I cannot create a persistent buffer in one process and write to it from another process?  I believe I can't use the persistent buffers memory with things like WriteProcessMemory()/ReadProcessMemory() between processes?

Comment: With those extensions would I have to map buffer in each process separately somehow each time they want to access the shared buffer?

Comment: There is this note that appears to indicate that the external memory object is GPU side only and doesn't allow mapping on the CPU: "An INVALID_OPERATION error is generated by Map*BufferRange if the specified buffer is referencing a memory object as its data store."?  I was specifically interested in the case of staging buffers used to upload to the GPU from multiple processes - also if all but one process could be oblivious to knowing it was even an OpenGL/Vulkan buffer they would write to.